# Conversion to polar coordinates of integral

Tags: integration

#### Conversion to polar coordinates of this integral:

$$\int_0^\sqrt{2} \int_y^\sqrt{4-y^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}\ dxdy $$

Comment: You have to at least try the obvious stuff that jumps out at you. You've seen $x^2+y^2=r^2$ before, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the region and see for yourself that in the polar coordinates, $r: 0 \to 2$, and $\theta: 0 \to \dfrac{\pi}{4}$, and $\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{1+r^2}$, and $dxdy = rdrd\theta$. So putting these together we have the new integral:

$I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^2 \dfrac{r}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}drd\theta$